# pure/const function attributes in different compilers

Tags: c++, gcc, constants, function-attributes

**pure** is a function attribute which says that a function does not modify any global memory.
**const** is a function attribute which says that a function does not read/modify any global memory.

Given that information, the compiler can do some additional optimisations.

Example for GCC:

```
float sigmoid(float x) __attribute__ ((const));

float calculate(float x, unsigned int C) {
    float sum = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i)
        sum += sigmoid(x);
    return sum;
}

float sigmoid(float x) { return 1.0f / (1.0f - exp(-x)); }
```

In that example, the compiler could optimise the function *calculate* to:

```
float calculate(float x, unsigned int C) {
    float sum = 0;
    float temp = C ? sigmoid(x) : 0.0f;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < C; ++i)
        sum += temp;
    return sum;
}
```

Or if your compiler is clever enough (and not so strict about floats):

```
float calculate(float x, unsigned int C) { return C ? sigmoid(x) * C : 0.0f; }
```

How can I mark a function in such way for the different compilers, i.e. GCC, Clang, ICC, MSVC or others?

Comment: For those of us that don't use gcc on a regular basis, perhaps you can post an explanation of what the pure/const attribute is.  If it is an optimization of some sort, an example of C or C++ code for which it helps the compiler generate more optimal assembly would be useful too.

Comment: I'm not a compiler writer, but it seems to me that such an attribute would be unnecessary if the `sigmoid()` function definition was available to the compiler *before* parsing `calculate()` in the same translation unit.  Regardless, these attributes could certainly be useful when the function definitions are in different translation units.

Comment: Yes, GCC (and other compilers) automatically add this attribute internally exactly in that case. And then, based on the attribute, they can do further optimisations (like in my example). And you exactly hit one of the main reasons for specifying it explicitely: If the compiler doesn't see the definition at that point or if the definition is not available at all or if you think that it is safe if the compiler reduces the amount of calls to the function.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- GCC: [pure/const function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)
- llvm-gcc: [supports the GCC pure/const attributes](http://llvm.org/releases/2.2/docs/ReleaseNotes.html)
- Clang: [seems to support it](http://llvm.org/releases/2.4/docs/ReleaseNotes.html) (I tried on a simple example with the GCC style attributes and it worked.)
- ICC: [seems to adopt the GCC attributes](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=62309) (Sorry, only a forum post.)
- MSVC: Seems not to support it. ([discussion](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804288/msvc-add-const-and-pure-like-function-attributes))

In general, it seems that almost all compilers support the GCC attributes. MSVC is so far the only compiler which does not support them (and which also doesn't have any alternative).

Comment: MSVC also has no intention to add support for those attributes: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804288/msvc-add-const-and-pure-like-function-attributes. They say they don't need it, which makes sense for applications, but not for libraries.

Comment: Think of GNU C as a language dialect, or set of language extensions.  You can test for the availability of a specific GNU C feature in any compiler using `#if __GNUC__ > 4 || ...` or similar, as recommended [in the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html).  Clang (and other compilers) only advertise a `__GNUC__` and `__GNUC_MINOR__` version that they fully support.  The implementation might be different from gcc's (e.g. clang's `__builtin_constant_p()` doesn't propagate const-ness into function args of inlined functions), but your code will compile.

Comment: In other words, clang and ICC might support a new feature from gcc 6.0, but will only define `__GNUC__` to 6 and `__GNUC_MINOR__` to 0 in versions that support *all* the language extensions that gcc6.0 does.

Comment: Dear @Albert MSVC actually supports the same notion of function attribute as `__atrribute__((const))` via `__declspec(noalias)`. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/noalias?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 12):

First, it's useful to note that "const" is a more strict version of
"pure", so "pure" can be used as a fallback if a compiler doesn't
implement "const".

As others have mentioned, MSVC doesn't really have anything similar,
but a lot of compilers have adopted the GCC syntax, including many
which don't define `__GNUC__` (and some which sometimes do and
sometimes don't, depending on flags).

- GCC supports
  [pure](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-pure-function-attribute)
  since 2.96+, and
  [const](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-const-function-attribute)
  since 2.5.0, in case you feel like checking the version.
- Clang supports both; you can use `__has_attribute(pure)` and
  `__has_attribute(const)` to detect them, but it's probably fine to
  just rely on clang setting `__GNUC__`. This also includes compilers
  based on clang like emscripten and XL C/C++ 13+.
- Intel C/C++ Compiler supports both, but their documentation is
  terrible so I have no idea when they were added. 16.0+ is certainly
  safe.
- Oracle Developer Studio [12.2+](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/pdf/821-1384.pdf) supports both.
- ARM C/C++ Compiler 4.1+ (and possibly older) supports both
  [pure](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/Cacigdac.html)
  and
  [const](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/Cacgigch.html)
- IBM XL C/C++ since at least [10.1](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27013159&aid=1).
- [TI 8.0+](http://downloads.ti.com/docs/esd/SPRUI04/index.html#SPRUI04B_HTML/tms320c6000-c-c-language-implementation.html#7.14.2_Function_Attributes%3FTocPath%3D7%2520TMS320C6000%2520C%252FC%252B%252B%2520Language%2520Implementation%7C7.14%2520GNU%2520Language%2520Extensions%7C_____2)
- [TI 7.3+](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/d/de/TMS320C6000_Optmizing_Compiler_v7.3_User's_Guide.pdf)
  with --gcc (detected with `__TI_GNU_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORT__`) supports both.
- PGI doesn't document it (AFAICT), but both attributes work (or are
  at least silently ignored). 17.10+ is safe, though they've probably
  been acceptable for much longer.

Of these, clang always defines `__GNUC__` and friends (currently to
4.2, IIRC). Intel defines `__GNUC__` by default (though it can be
suppressed with -no-gcc) as does PGI in C++ mode (but not in C
mode). The others you'll have to check for manually.

Oracle Developer Studio has also supported pragmas since it was known
as [Forte Developer
6](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/fortec6u2/806-7984/806-7984.pdf). They're
used a bit differently since they require you to specify the function
name:

```
/* pure: */
#pragma does_not_write_global_data (funcname)
/* const; SPARC-only until 12.2 */
#pragma no_side_effect (funcname)
```

TI 6.0+ (at least) supports a `#pragma FUNC_IS_PURE;` pragma in C++
mode only. In C mode, it's `#pragma FUNC_IS_PURE(funcname);`.

Most of this can be hidden behind a macro, which is what I've done in
[Hedley](https://github.com/nemequ/hedley):

```
#if \
  HEDLEY_GNUC_HAS_ATTRIBUTE(pure,2,96,0) || \
  HEDLEY_INTEL_VERSION_CHECK(16,0,0) || \
  HEDLEY_SUNPRO_VERSION_CHECK(5,11,0) || \
  HEDLEY_ARM_VERSION_CHECK(4,1,0) || \
  HEDLEY_IBM_VERSION_CHECK(10,1,0) || \
  HEDLEY_TI_VERSION_CHECK(8,0,0) || \
  (HEDLEY_TI_VERSION_CHECK(7,3,0) && defined(__TI_GNU_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORT__)) || \
  HEDLEY_PGI_VERSION_CHECK(17,10,0)
#  define HEDLEY_PURE __attribute__((__pure__))
#elif HEDLEY_TI_VERSION_CHECK(6,0,0) && defined(__cplusplus)
#  define HEDLEY_NO_RETURN _Pragma("FUNC_IS_PURE;")
#else
#  define HEDLEY_PURE
#endif

#if HEDLEY_GNUC_HAS_ATTRIBUTE(const, 2, 5, 0) || \
  HEDLEY_INTEL_VERSION_CHECK(16,0,0) || \
  HEDLEY_SUNPRO_VERSION_CHECK(5,11,0) || \
  HEDLEY_ARM_VERSION_CHECK(4,1,0) || \
  HEDLEY_IBM_VERSION_CHECK(10,1,0) || \
  HEDLEY_TI_VERSION_CHECK(8,0,0) || \
  (HEDLEY_TI_VERSION_CHECK(7,3,0) && defined(__TI_GNU_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORT__)) || \
  HEDLEY_PGI_VERSION_CHECK(17,10,0)
#  define HEDLEY_CONST __attribute__((__const__))
#else
#  define HEDLEY_CONST HEDLEY_PURE
#endif
```

This doesn't include the variants which would require the function
names as an argument, but it still covers the *vast* majority of
users, and it's safe to use everywhere.

If you don't want to use Hedley (it's a single public domain / CC0 header) it
shouldn't be too difficult to replace the internal version macros. If
you choose to do that, you should probably base your port on the
Hedley repo instead of this answer as I'm much more likely to keep it
up to date.

Answer (score 1):

As an update for anyone reading this after all these years, starting with C++11 (and with continuous improvements with C++14, C++17 and C++20), the [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) keyword was added to the language, letting you mark functions, methods, statements, templates, variables (pretty much everything) as absolutely and completely constant, allowing for nice optimization from the compiler.

[`constevel`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) and [`constinit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constinit) were also added in C++20 to further expand the compile-time capabilities of the language.