# Is performance of using readonly variable directly different from storing in object then using it?

Tags: c++, optimization, reference, constants, copy-constructor

I have a simple function which is similar to this :

```
int foo(const Data& a, int pos)
{
    Big_obj x= (pos==1?a.x : a.y);//I just use x for reading
    return x.elem*x.elem;
}
```

(suppose that I forgot to store object by reference `const Big_obj& x=...`)

Can today compilers optimize that into following code ? :

```
int foo(const Data& a, int pos)
{
    if (pos == 1)
      return a.x.elem * a.x.elem;
    else 
      return a.y.elem * a.y.elem;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make (hyper-trivial) examples of both, compile (with varying levels of optimization if you're so inclined) both, and take a peek at the assembly? Personally, I believe they will be optimized to approximately, but not the exact same, code... until you crank up the optimization. But take that guess with a grain of salt, I've only done similar things with for loops.

Comment: The compiler would have to proof that the (copy-)constructor of `Big_obj` has no side effects. That is quite difficult. I would look at the assembler code and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GCC there is a very useful compiler switch: `-fdump-tree-optimized` which will show the code after the performed optimizations.

You can discover that it all depends on `Big_obj`.

E.g.

```
struct Big_obj
{
  int elem;
  int vect[1000];
};

struct Data { Big_obj x, y; };
```

and `g++ -Wall -O3 -fdump-tree-optimized` will produce a *.165t.optimized* file containing:

```
int foo(const Data&, int) (const struct Data & a, int pos)
{
  int x$elem;
  const struct Big_obj * iftmp.4;
  int _8;

  <bb 2>:
  if (pos_2(D) == 1)
    goto <bb 3>;
  else
    goto <bb 4>;

  <bb 3>:
  iftmp.4_4 = &a_3(D)->x;
  goto <bb 5>;

  <bb 4>:
  iftmp.4_5 = &a_3(D)->y;

  <bb 5>:
  # iftmp.4_1 = PHI <iftmp.4_4(3), iftmp.4_5(4)>
  x$elem_7 = MEM[(const struct Big_obj &)iftmp.4_1];
  _8 = x$elem_7 * x$elem_7;
  return _8;
}
```

This is exactly the optimized code you posted. But if you change `Big_obj` (`vect` type has been changed from array to `std::vector`):

```
struct Big_obj
{
  int elem;
  std::vector<int> vect;
};
```

**the optimization won't be performed anymore** (i.e. `foo()` will also allocate/deallocate memory for `x.vect`).

In the example the reason is that optimizations must be implemented according to the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if): only code transformations that do not change the observable behavior of the program are allowed.

`operator new` could have a *custom* implementation counting how many times it gets called (and this is hard to detect). But even without a custom `operator new`, there are other issues (see [Does allocating memory and then releasing constitute a side effect in a C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624022/does-allocating-memory-and-then-releasing-constitute-a-side-effect-in-a-c-prog)).

With other compilers you have to study the assembly code (e.g. `clang++ -S` switch), but the same holds true.

Comment: I try that in gcc . It's interesting to know in gcc it does not even call that function and compute it directly :) https://www.dropbox.com/s/k5bhbvg1ino0mro/optimize.cpp and https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fiyhzx5zix6d88/main.cpp