# Why is Objective-C sqrtf() function faster than a function that just returns a value?

Tags: objective-c, performance, sqrt

I have these functions in Objective-C:

```
-(void)emptyFunction
{
    NSTimeInterval startTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    float b;
    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        b = [self returnNr:i];
    }

    NSTimeInterval endTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    double elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    NSLog(@"1. %f", elapsedTime);
}

-(float)returnNr:(float)number
{
    return number;
}
```

and

```
-(void)sqrtFunction
{
    NSTimeInterval startTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    float b;
    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        b = sqrtf(i);
    }

    NSTimeInterval endTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    double elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    NSLog(@"2. %f", elapsedTime);
}
```

When I call them, in any order, it prints in console the following:

```
2014-01-13 12:23:00.458 RapidTest[443:70b] 1. 0.011970
2014-01-13 12:23:00.446 RapidTest[443:70b] 2. 0.006308
```

How is this happening? How can *sqrtf()* function be **twice as** faster than a function that just returns a value? I know sqrtf() works on bits with assembly language and such, but faster than just a return? How is it possible?

Comment: i guess sqrt() function is C-level, more near to system and it uses register data type.

Comment: One difference is that `emptyFunction` and `sqrtFunction` are methods not functions and `sqrt()` is a C-Level function like `AnoopVaidya` has said. Methods are **NOT** functions there is a big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `[self returnNr:i]` is not the same as simply calling a C function. Instead you're sending a message to `self`, which gets translated to the equivalent in C:

```
objc_msgSend(self, @selector(returnNr:), i);
```

This will eventually call your returnNr: implementation, but there's some overhead involved. For more details on what's going on in `objc_msgSend` see [objc_msgSend tour](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/) or [Let's build objc_msgSend](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-11-16-lets-build-objc_msgsend.html)

[edit]
Also see [An Illustrated History of objc_msgSend](http://sealiesoftware.com/msg/index.html), which shows how the implementation changed over time. Executing the code from your Q will have resulted in different results on different platform versions because of improvements / trade-offs made during the evolution of `objc_msgSend`.

Comment: DAMN nice answer. Changed _returnNr_ to a simple C function and it's, as it should be, faster than the _sqrtFunction_. Thanks for the in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your Obj-C method

```
-(float)returnNr:(float)number
{
    return number;
}
```

first gets compiled to C-function and then it is executed, and `sqrtf()` is a C-function.

Hence C-functions will be faster as compared to Objective-C methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your benchmark is flawed.

First, in both cases a compiler may optimize your loop as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000000-1; i++) {
    [self returnNr:i];
}
float b = [self returnNr:i];
```

respectively:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000000-1; i++) {
    sqrtf(i);
}
float b = sqrtf(i);
```

Then, IFF the compiler can deduce that the statement `sqrtf(i)` has no side effect (other than returning a value), it may further optimize as follows:

```
float b = sqrtf(1000000-1);
```

It's very likely that clang will apply this optimization, though it's implementation dependent.

See also: [Do C and C++ optimizers typically know which functions have no side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233497/do-c-and-c-optimizers-typically-know-which-functions-have-no-side-effects)

In case of Objective-C method invocations a compiler has far less optimization opportunities, and it will very likely always assume that a method call might have a possible side effect and must be called *always*. Thus, the second optimization will likely not applied in an optimized build.

Additionally, your approach to measure the elapsed time is by far not accurate enough. You should use the mach timer to get a precise absolute time. And you need to execute a number of "runs" and take the minimum of the runs.