# How to declare and define a pure function in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc

GCC has the pure and const attributes, where const is actually used for the real pure functions (pure is for [idempotent functions which are also side-effect free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233497/do-c-and-c-optimizers-typically-know-which-functions-have-no-side-effects#comment23238484_16233667)).

So how do I declare and define a function using the const-attribute?

**Edit:** I'm interested in the real pure functions, the ones declared with the const-attribute, not the ones declared with the pure-attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example:

```
// Declaration:
int square (int x) __attribute__ ((const));
// Definition:
int __attribute__ ((const)) square (int x)
{ 
    return x*x; 
}
```

---

The syntax for all attributes is pretty much the same: `__attribute__ (( <attribute-name> ))`, or `__attribute__ (( <attribute-name> ( <attribute-options> ) ))`. Quoting from the documentation you link to:

> The keyword `__attribute__` allows you to specify special attributes when making a declaration. This keyword is followed by an attribute specification inside double parentheses.

There are examples in the documentation you link to for several other attributes, including `pure`:

> ```
> int square (int) __attribute__ ((pure));
> ```

so all you need, syntax-wise, to use `const`, is change `pure` to `const`:

> ```
> int square (int) __attribute__ ((const));
> ```

As pointed out in the comments: if you're using it in a definition, then you need to put `__attribute__ ((const))` in a different location:

```
int square (int) __attribute__ ((const)) { ... } // doesn't work
int __attribute__ ((const)) square (int) { ... } // does work
```

but the `const` and `pure` attributes are pretty much only useful if they are applied to external declarations, so that shouldn't be a problem. If the definition is visible, GCC is usually able to determine whether the function can be treated as `const`/`pure` without your help.

Answer (score 6):

According this [this article](http://lwn.net/Articles/285332/), the syntax matches with what @hvd says:

```
int square (int) __attribute__ ((pure));
```

However, it seems that `gcc` does not enforce the property of not examining global state when I compile the following example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int square (int) __attribute__ ((pure));

int outerX = 7;
int square(int x) {
   return outerX * x; 
}

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", square(5));
    return 0;
}
```

The following prints no errors, and the code runs and produces `35`.

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic -O3 Pure.c


gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
```

Even more curiously, `gcc` also does not care if we mutate the global state inside the function and return a different value on each call because of a change it caused in the global state.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int square (int) __attribute__ ((pure));

int outerX = 7;
int square(int x) {
   outerX++;
   return outerX * x; 
}

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", square(5));
    printf("%d\n", square(5));
    printf("%d\n", square(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
40
45
50
```

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is a bit misleading, I think: whether a function is pure depends on what it does, not how it does it. If a function is pure even though it reads global variables (for example, because those variables never change), then it may be declared as pure. Because of that, the compiler cannot enforce the attribute.

Comment: It still makes sense with your edit: `int pure(void) __attribute__((pure)); int pure(void) { static bool pureInited = false; static int pureValue; if (!pureInited) { pureValue = ...; pureInited = true; } return pureValue; }` I think the `pure` attribute can be applied there, even though the function modifies variables with static storage duration: the effect is still that the function always returns the exact same value. (`const` might make sense here too, rather than `pure`.)

Comment: @hvd, Do you think the compiler will yell if the function returns different values on each call with the same arguments?

Comment: @hvd, See my edit. I'm starting to doubt whether that attribute does anything at all.

Comment: *"I'm starting to doubt whether that attribute does anything at all."* hvd suggests in his answer it might only override compiler analysis when used on extern functions... might explain why it hasn't seemed to kick in for your mutating test.

Comment: @tonyd I have not been able to produce an example that causes even compiler warning yet even with external declarations.

Comment: @merlin2011: compiler warnings might be too much to hope for, but I guess that means you're not seeing `40` each time either...?

Comment: @tonyd correct.  I haven't seen unexpected output yet either

Comment: @merlin2011: all good insights to have captured here... +1 from me.

Comment: @merlin2011 Yeah, if the function gets inlined, the optimiser cannot see the attributes any longer. Also, `printf` may modify global state, and `pure` functions may depend on global state, so that forces another call as well. With `__attribute__((const))`, and `-O`, but not `-O2`, I do see `40` printed thrice.

Comment: @hvd A non-static function won't be inlined unless you explicitly declare it with `inline`.

Comment: @MarkYisri Just try it yourself: `void f() { puts("Hello, world!"); } int main() { f(); }`. With `gcc -O2`, if you inspect the generated assembly, you'll see a call directly to `puts` inside `main`.

Comment: @hvd Inside `main`? Yes, it could skip the function call overhead there. However, the compiler cannot skip emitting a full `f` function as well, because another file may reference it with `extern void f();`.

Comment: @MarkYisri The compiler generally cannot, but unused external functions can be dropped once all translation units are available. And that is irrelevant. You claimed the function wouldn't be inlined, but it was.

Comment: @hvd Fair enough. I was incorrect about the inlining. However, the dropping of unused functions is dependent on the linker that is used.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with C++11 one can use an [attribute specifier sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) to specify such attributes. For example:

```
[[ gnu::const ]]
int square (int x)
{ 
    return x * x; 
}
```

Also, starting with C++17 all attributes unknown to a compiler are ignored without causing an error. So the code above becomes portable between different compilers and platforms.