# What is the point of making an argument that is passed by value constant?

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-value

This is more of a general question:
Is there any point in making a function parameter `const` if it is being passed by value?

In a code I am studying, I see a lot of the following:

```
void some_function(const std::vector<double> some_vec);
```

`std::vector` is passed by value, so what then is the point of the `const`?

Like I would understand if the function was instead passing the vector by reference as such:

```
void some_function(const std::vector<double> &some_vec);
```

but I see no point in the `const` in the former.

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204500/when-and-for-what-purposes-should-the-const-keyword-be-used-in-c-for-variables

Comment: Different question (asks about primitives explicitly), but a related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292490/is-it-better-to-remove-const-in-front-of-primitive-types-used-as-function-pa

Comment: If a compiler knows that something is const, it can use this information and possibly achieve higher program efficiency due to optimizations (and also prevents you to modify that object accidentally). However, making a passed-by-value parameter `const` in a function declaration does not make sense. On the contrary, it does in a function definition.

Comment: @DanielLangr When you say "However, making a passed-by-value parameter const in a function declaration does not make sense. On the contrary, it does in a function definition." I thought the function declaration prototype has to match its respective declaration? Like if you make a declaration with `const` parameters, then your function definition must also use `const` for the parameters?

Comment: @Iamanon Have you looked at the question linked by StoryTeller? Namely his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46292715/580083.

Comment: @DanielLangr Just read it. I didn't know that.

Comment: The dupe given as justification for the closure is not a dupe actually. It asks and answers a (slightly) different question. I vote for re-opening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that you prevent the function body from altering the value. The function argument is just an automatic variable within the function body and you may want to ensure it remains at its input value. Consider

```
int foo(int x)
{
    /* lots of code */
    some_other_func(x);  // may modify x
    /* even more code */
    return x+42;         // x may have been modified
}
```

and

```
int foo(const int x)
{
    /* lots of code */
    some_other_func(x);  // will not compile if x is taken by non-const reference
    /* even more code */
    return x+42;         // x is guaranteed at its input value
}
```

As a rule of thumb, declare everything `const` that is not meant to be altered. Then, if you or somebody accidentally attempts to alter such a variable, a compile-time error will result.

Note also that the `const` declarator has no effect in a function declaration, but only in the function definition, i.e. the following is perfectly fine (in fact recommended):

```
struct bar
{
   int foo(int) const;
   /* more code */
};

int bar::foo(const int x) const // possibly in another compilation unit
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It can be *very* useful when working with mathematical code in particular, as it stops errant refactorers from changing variables passed in as function parameters. For example, you don't want to mess about with the value of *pi* (which, annoyingly, is not part of the C++ standard), or things like the gravitational constant, &c.

(In the past I *have* seen `pi *= 2;` as the code was written by a physicist who was convinced that *pi* ought to be twice as big as most folk would have it.)

It's also nice to have the qualifiers matching in a function declaration and definition (although the language itself doesn't insist on that).

I don't use it much admittedly.

Comment: In pure declarations, though?

Comment: @StoryTeller: I think it's nice if the declarations and definitions match, although of course some folk take the opposite view, especially when it comes to `const` parameters.

Comment: This may feel nice, but doing a refactor on a core function and changing the qualifier (either way) can cause an entire system to need a re-build (admittedly it's because our build systems don't rely on semantic information, but still). The mere thought of it makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Interesting. There are are a few physicists who are convinced that *pi* should be defined as *2 * pi*. I kid you not; but I have see `pi *= 2;` in code!

Comment: const qualify pi all you want (not a bad idea at all). But ultimately it's an implementation detail of the function. It should not leak into a header, no matter how much the symmetry appeals to oneself.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Out of interest, are you a 2pi guy?

Comment: I uh... don't feel comfortable answering that

Comment: @StoryTeller: Oh but you should! What about Planck's constant?

Comment: I like Planck's constant.  I think it is better than Avogadro's number ;)

Comment: There's a solid argument for that "pi is wrong" because tau (2*pi) is the actual, natural number (and of course, that seems to be quite the emotional controversity). Either way `pi *= 2;` is just misleading, but surely nobody would mind `double tau = 2 * pi;` (pun intended)