# Why can I add "const" to value parameters but not to reference parameters on member definition?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Look at this code:

```
struct A{
    void f(int);
    void g(int&);
};

// this works, defines A::f(int);
void A::f(const int){// no compiler error here despite additional const
};

// why does this not work the same way with references?
void A::g(const int&){// compiler error here because of additional const
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Why can I define `A::f(int)` with a`A::f(const int)` definition but something similar does not work for reference parameters like `int&`?

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53834815/509868)

Comment: [This](https://abseil.io/tips/109) might be what you looking for.

Comment: @wsys Thank you. "const type-specifiers buried within a parameter type specification are significant". Now I know what I observe it is intended behavior.

Comment: Classical case of toxic stack overflow: No one explained what is the reasoning behind, question is closed with a "duplicate" that is not a duplicate. I don't find the answer there. I know why adding const is useful and I know that it does not change the signature in the first case, but does change the signature in the second. BUT WHY IS DESIGN CHOSEN LIKE THAT?