# c++ override virtual function with const parameter instead of non-const parameter

Tags: c++, overriding, constants, signature

When I was writing an overide function with const parameter instead of non-const parameter, I thought the compiler would report an error, because the base function has non-const parameter, but it succeeded to compile it. Why?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual uint64_t cal(uint64_t value)
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
        return value;
    }
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    uint64_t cal(const uint64_t value) override;
};
uint64_t B::cal(const uint64_t value)
{
  std::cout << value + 1 << std::endl; 
  return (value+1);
}
int main()
{
    B b;
    b.cal(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the cv qualifier of the parameter is ignored.

Comment: Yeah, top-level const is not part of the function signature. This is why you very often see `const` being omitted in function prototypes but only specified in the implementations, in order not to litter the API with `const` qualifiers.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `const` has somewhat weird behavior. It applies to what's on the *left* of it, not to what's on the right. But is there's nothing on the left of it, *then* (and only then) does it apply to what's on the right of it. So `const char*` is actually the same as `char const*`, but not the same as `char* const`. `char* const` is top-level const, `const char*` is **not**, because the former is a non-const pointer, the latter is a const pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why?

Because the top const qualifier of a function argument is ignored in a declaration.

```
uint64_t cal(uint64_t value);
```

and

```
uint64_t cal(const uint64_t value);
```

declare the exact same type of function. `cal` is a function taking a `uint64_t` and returning a `uint64_t`. The `const` qualifier makes no difference for calling code, since `value` is always a *copy* of the passed in argument.

The only difference is in the function body, where the `const` qualifier will prevent you from modifying the paraemter. But that is an implementation detail.

This difference can even raise coding style questions. For instance see

[Is it better to remove "const" in front of "primitive" types used as function parameters in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292490/is-it-better-to-remove-const-in-front-of-primitive-types-used-as-function-pa)

Answer (score 5):

Note that top-level cv-qualifiers are dropped when considering function type, so `uint64_t cal(uint64_t)` and `uint64_t cal(const uint64_t)` are considered as the same [function type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Parameter_list).

(emphasis mine)

> The type of each function parameter in the parameter list is determined according to the following rules:
>
> 4) **Top-level cv-qualifiers are dropped from the parameter type (This adjustment only affects the function type, but doesn't modify the property of the parameter**: `int f(const int p, decltype(p)*);` and `int f(int, const int*);` declare the same function)

Answer (score 3):

Top level `const` of parameters is not a part of the signature of the function. The only requirement for overloading is that the signatures must match.

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<int(int), int(const int)>);
}
```

[Compiles fine](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/mHy-Qh)