# (C language) Calling a sqrt() function inside loop header

Tags: c, performance, for-loop, c++17

If I write my prime check function like her.,

```
for(int i=2; i<=sqrt(n); ++i) {//code}
```

Will that sqrt() calculated for every iteration or the C compiler is smart enough to calculate the sqrt once and store the result ?

1. Assume n as a constant
2. I know register could be used for loop variable
3. Mine is gcc lastest version compiler

Any suggestion would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: Go to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) (or just use your terminal) to see what assembly is generated. Godbolt will even show which instructions correspond to every line of your code.

Comment: Sure. It's time to dive in assembly

Comment: Hint: If you're looking to optimise, the only _even_ prime number is `2`. All other primes are _odd_. (The known ones, at least.) Use a special case for `2`, then start at `3` and use `i += 2` to step from _odd_ to _odd_... Cut processing down by 50%.

Comment: If the loop is used for prime checking, you could use `i <= n / i;` as condition. Chances are that you are going to evaluate `n % i` in the body and compilers know that some architectures can calculate both the quotient and the remainder with a single instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the compiler can reliably establish that `n` indeed never changes, it is free to optimise it by calculating it up front. This behaviour (an implementation basically rewriting your code for efficiency as long as the *effect* is the same) is true of all code.

However, this "reliable establishment" may *not* be as easy as you think :-)

If you don't want to concern yourself with the possibility that it may not be detected as constant, simply do it yourself with something like:

```c
double sqrn = sqrt(n);
for (int i = 2; i <= sqrn; ++i) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: It should be noted this optimization can be made only because `sqrt` is a standard function with known effects. If a program calls some other function instead, it could have side effects such as update static objects, and the compiler could not eliminate the calls without additional information.

Comment: @Eric, a compiler with knowledge of an *arbitrary* function that is guaranteed to be the one that's used, could just as easily figure out that it had no side effects. In fact, that raises another point - I think that, unless the compiler *knows* that the `sqrt` you will use (link with) *is* the standard one, it cannot safely make that assumption. You may link with a different one.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to assume the `sqrt` that will be used is one that conforms to the C standard’s specification for `sqrt` because `sqrt` is reserved for use as an external identifier for this purpose. If you link with a non-conforming `sqrt`, the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Actually, I did not know that, @EricPostpischil. I wasn't sure you were correct but it's actually right there in 7.1.3 (in C17).

Comment: Some compilers allow you to use attributes to declare a function idempotent. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405492/how-to-declare-and-define-a-pure-function-in-gcc for example.