# The max number of digits in an int based on number of bits

Tags: c

So, I needed a constant value to represent the max number of digits in an int, and it needed to be calculated at compile time to pass into the size of a char array.

To add some more detail: The compiler/machine I'm working with has a very limited subset of the C language, so none of the std libraries work as they have unsupported features. As such I cannot use INT_MIN/MAX as I can neither include them, nor are they defined.

I need a compile time expression that calculates the size. The formula I came up with is:

```
((sizeof(int) / 2) * 3 + sizeof(int)) + 2
```

It is marginally successful with n byte integers based on hand calculating it.

```
sizeof(int)  INT_MAX               characters    formula
2           32767                       5            7
4           2147483647                  10           12
8           9223372036854775807         19           22
```

Comment: Do you mean the maximum number of *decimal* digits?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: That's a good point. I assumed decimal digits. If the OP wants binary digits then please downvote the hell out of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I should have been more explicit that the compiler/machine I'm working on can't include any std libraries as they have unsupported features.
As such I don't have access to MAX_INT or MIN_INT either.

Comment: @BenSeawalker, if you read chux's answer and mine, you'll see that although they describe the solution in terms of `MAX_INT` or `MIN_INT`, ultimately they do not depend on those macros.  chux's does depend on `CHAR_BIT`, but there is very little risk in replacing that with literal 8.

Comment: With that said, every conforming C implementation, including freestanding ones such as it sounds like you are using, supports use of the features defined by a specified subset of the standard library headers.  That subset includes `limits.h`, wherein are defined the `INT_MAX`, `INT_MIN`, and `CHAR_BIT` macros.  If you cannot use that header then your implementation is non-conforming.  Effectively, it is not C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are correct, it is a proprietary C-like language. Entirely my fault for not explaining that.

Comment: @BenSeawalker, with respect to `MAX_INT` values, the ones you have edited into the question are the maximum values of *unsigned* integers expressed in the specified numbers of 8-bit bytes, without padding.  I don't know about your language, but C's `int`s are signed, which consumes one bit, halving (close enough) the maximum expressible values.

Comment: This is a good question now. (I'll remove the explicit EDIT). -3 is not appropriate.

Comment: @BenSeawalker `INT_MAX` and `65536` is confusing in the table.  On 16-bit machines `INT_MAX` is typically `32767`.  Are you looking for an answer concerning `int` or `unsigned`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for a result related to a logarithm of the maximum value of the integer type in question (*which* logarithm depends on the radix of the representation whose digits you want to count).  You cannot compute exact logarithms at compile time, but you can write macros that estimate them closely enough for your purposes, or that compute a close enough upper bound for your purposes.  For example, see [How to compute log with the preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581671/2402272).

It is useful also to know that you can convert between logarithms in different bases by multiplying by appropriate constants.  In particular, if you know the base-*a* logarithm of a number and you want the base-*b* logarithm, you can compute it as

log<sub>b</sub>(*x*) = log<sub>a</sub>(*x*) / log<sub>a</sub>(b)

Your case is a bit easier than the general one, though.  For the dimension of an array that is not a variable-length array, you need an "integer constant expression".  Furthermore, your result does not need more than two digits of precision (three if you wanted the number of *binary* digits) for any built-in integer type you'll find in a C implementation, and it seems like you need only a close enough upper bound.

Moreover, you get a head start from the `sizeof` operator, which can appear in integer constant expressions and which, when applied to an integer type, gives you an upper bound on the base-256 logarithm of values of that type (supposing that `CHAR_BIT` is 8).  This estimate is very tight if every bit is a value bit, but signed integers have a sign bit, so this bound is a bit looser for them. It is a bit looser for integer representations that have padding bits as well.

If you want a bound on the number of digits in a power-of-two radix then you can use `sizeof` pretty directly.  Let's suppose, though, that you're looking for the number of *decimal* digits.  Mathematically, the maximum number of digits in the decimal representation of an `int` is

N = ceil(log<sub>10</sub>(`MAX_INT`))

or

N = floor(log<sub>10</sub>(`MAX_INT`)) + 1

provided that `MAX_INT` is not a power of 10.  Let's express that in terms of the base-256 logarithm:

N = floor( log<sub>256</sub>(`MAX_INT`) / log<sub>256</sub>(10) ) + 1

Now, log<sub>256</sub>(10) cannot be part of an integer constant expression, but it or its reciprocal *can* be pre-computed: 1 / log<sub>256</sub>(10) ≈ 2.40824.  Now, let's use that to rewrite our expression:

N <= floor( sizeof(int) * 2.40824 ) + 1

That's not yet an integer constant expression, but it's close.  This  expression *is* an integer constant expression, and a good enough approximation to serve your purpose:

N = 241 * sizeof(int) / 100 + 1

Here are the results for various integer sizes:

```
sizeof(int)          INT_MAX   True N  Computed N
    1                    127      3        3
    2                  32767      5        5
    4             2147483648     10       10
    8       ~9.223372037e+18     19       20
```

(The values in the `INT_MAX` and `True N` columns suppose one of the allowed forms of signed representation, and no padding bits; the former and maybe both will be smaller if the representation contains padding bits.)

I presume that in the unlikely event that you encounter a system with 8-byte `int`s, the extra one byte you provide for your digit array will not break you.  The discrepancy arises from the difference between having (at most) 63 value bits in a signed 64-bit integer, and the formula accounting for 64 value bits in that case, with the result that `sizeof(int)` is a bit too much of an overestimation of the base-256 log of `INT_MAX`.  The formula gives exact results for `unsigned int` up to at least size 8, provided there are no padding bits.

As a macro, then:

```
// Expands to an integer constant expression evaluating to a close upper bound
// on the number of decimal digits in a value expressible in the
// integer type given by the argument (if it an integer type name) or the
// type of the argument (if it is an expression with integer type).
#define DECIMAL_DIGITS_BOUND(t) (241 * sizeof(t) / 100 + 1)
```

Comment: Although this answer is wonderfully comprehensive I think it bypasses (in places) some tricky corners: an `int` could have padding bits. The `sizeof` table you have, to be pedantic, is misleading. Not even IEEE754 places requirements on the accuracy of `log`, so you need to be careful there too. I remain convinced that the only portable way you can solve this is to define constants solely on the value of `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Thanks for the UV, @Bathsheba.  I agree that `int` representation can have padding bits, and that the table describes the cases where there are none, but the answer only needs to and aims to provide an *upper bound* on the maximum number of decimal digits.  I will clarify that that's what it provides.  The accuracy of the library's `log()` function is irrelevant, however, because it is not used here.  I agree that if you want the tightest possible bound in the presence of padding bits, then you need to use something based on `INT_MAX`, but the OP says in comments that `INT_MAX` cannot be used.

Comment: Note: `241 * sizeof(t) / 100` makes the assumption `CHAR_BIT==8` - which is extremely common, though not specified.

Comment: Yes indeed, @chux, and though it may be hard to spot in this lengthy answer, I do specify that that is a proviso (middle of the fourth paragraph).

Answer (score 3):

An upper bound on the number of decimal digits an `int` may produce depends on `INT_MIN`.

```
// Mathematically 
max_digits = ceil(log10(-INT_MAX))
```

It is easier to use the bit-width of the `int` as that approximates a log of `-INT_MIN`. `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT - 1` is the max number of *value bits* in an `int`.

```
// Mathematically 
max_digits = ceil((sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT - 1)* log10(2))
// log10(2) --> ~ 0.30103
```

On rare machines, `int` has padding, so the above will over estimate.

For log10(2), which is about 0.30103, we could use `1/3` or one-third.

As a macro, perform integer math and add 1 for the *ceiling*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define INT_DIGIT10_WIDTH ((sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT - 1)/3 + 1)
```

To account for a sign and null character add 2, use the following.  With a very tight log10(2) fraction to not over calculate the buffer needs:

```
#define INT_STRING_SIZE ((sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT - 1)*28/93 + 3)
```

Note 28/93 = ‭0.3010752... > log2(10)

---

The number of digits needed for any base down to base 2 would need follows below.  It is interesting that +2 is needed and not +1.  Consider a 2 bit signed number in base 2 could be `"-10"`, a size of 4.

```
#define INT_STRING2_SIZE ((sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT + 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
((sizeof(int) / 2) * 3 + sizeof(int)) + 2
```

is the formula I came up with. 
The +2 is for the negative sign and the null terminator.

Comment: Actually, I take back my downvote. Although crude this does the job in a surprisingly large number of cases. If you surround it with compiler and platform-specific `#define`s, it approaches robustness too.

Answer (score 1):

Boringly, I think you need to hardcode this, centred around inspecting `sizeof(int)` and consulting your compiler documentation to see what kind of `int` you actually have. (All the C standard specifies is that it can't be smaller than a `short`, and needs to have a range of at least -32767 to +32767, and 1's complement, 2's complement, and signed magnitude can be chosen. The manner of storage is arbitrary although big and little endianness are common.) Note that *an arbitrary number of padding bits are allowed*, so you can't, in full generality, impute the number of decimal digits from the `sizeof`.

C doesn't support the level of compile time evaluable constant expressions you'd need for this.

So hardcode it and make your code intentionally brittle so that compilation fails if a compiler encounters a case that you have not thought of.

You could solve this in C++ using `constexpr` and metaprogramming techniques.

Comment: C++ might provide this out of the box: `constexpr const int digits = std::numeric_limits<int>::digits10`; not sure, however, how portable this is.

Comment: Ha! What will the C++ standards committee think of next?

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that integral values are either 2, 4, or 8 bytes, and if we determine the respective digits to be 5, 10, 20, then a integer constant expression yielding the exact values could be written as follows:

```
const int digits = (sizeof(int)==8) ? 20 : ((sizeof(int)==4) ? 10 : 5);
int testArray[digits];
```

I hope that I did not miss something essential. I've tested this at file scope.

Comment: The post asks for "max number of digits in an int based on number of bits
".  That would be 19 for a 64-bit `int`, not 20  as `INT_MAX` in that case is 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 - a 19 digit number.  20 would make sense for an `unsigned`, but that was not the question.

Comment: @chux: right; `std::numeric_limits<int>::digits10` also gives `19`; but I decided to overtake OP's hand calculated values.