# storing digits of a number in array

Tags: arrays, c, loops, digits, unsigned-integer

How do I store different digits of an integer in any array
like 1234 to {1,2,3,4}
It can be done using `char str[]="1234"; printf("%c",str[0];` 
but how to do it without using string and in integer itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet that creates an array of digits and prints them out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Print digits 1 by 1
void numToDigits (int number, int base) {
  int i;
  int n_digits = (int)ceil(log(number+1) / log(base));
  printf("%d digits\n", n_digits);
  int * digits = calloc(n_digits, sizeof(int));

  for (i=0; i<n_digits; ++i) {
    digits[i] = number % base;
    number /= base;
  }

  // digits[0] is the 1's place, so print them starting from the largest index

  for (i=n_digits-1; i>=0; --i) {
    printf("%d", digits[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  free(digits);
}
```

You'll likely want to modify this, but I think it exposes all the important ideas. Don't forget to add `-lm` when you compile to include math libraries needed for `log` and `ceil`. Also note that the printing code isn't made to work with bases larger than 10.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method, more or less:

- get the `log10()` of the integer to determine its 'size'
- take the `floor()` of that to get exponent (number of digits - 1)
- then calculate the highest divider with `(int)pow(10, exponent)`
- finally have a `for`-loop:

  ```
  int value = 1234; // Your value to split up in digits.
  for (int d = divider; divider > 0; divider /= 10)
  {
      int digit = value / d;
      value = value / 10;

      // Store digit in array
  }
  ```

I leave the details for you to fill in.

[Carson had a similar idea which nicely avoids the use of `pow()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72206261/1971013)

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports variable length arrays then you can use the approach shown in the demonstration program below

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { Base = 10 };

size_t size( unsigned int x )
{
    size_t n = 0;
    do { ++n; } while ( x /= Base );

    return n; 
}

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int x = 0;

    printf( "Enter a non-negative number: " );
    scanf( "%u", &x );

    size_t n = size( x );
    unsigned int digits[n];

    for ( size_t i = n; i != 0; x /= Base )
    {
        digits[--i] = x % Base;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%u", digits[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number: 123456789
123456789
```

If the compiler does not support variable length arrays then you will need to allocate the array dynamically as for example

```
unsigned int *digits = malloc( n * sizeof( unsigned int ) );
```

Comment: No need for VLA or malloc, just have array which fits the largest possible value of the type.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to calculate how many digits are in a given integer `n` at runtime. You can check your compiler's `<limits.h>` for the maximum number of digits an `int` can hold.

```
int n = 124343;
int digits[10]; // INT_MAX is 10-digit long on x86 and x64 (GCC and Clang)
int ndigits;
```

Another solution is to [pre-compute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43788824/16835308) ([@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359)) the maximum number of digits using macros:

```
#define INT_DIGIT10_WIDTH ((sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT - 1)/3 + 1)
int digits[INT_DIGIT10_WIDTH];
```

The rest is simple:

```
// Digits are stored in reverse order
for (ndigits = 0; n; n /= 10)
    digits[ndigits++] = n % 10;

for (int i = ndigits - 1; i > 0; --i)
    printf("%d\t", digits[i]);
```

If you want to store them in-order:

```
// Digits are stored in reverse order
for (ndigits = 0; n; n /= 10)
    digits[ndigits++] = n % 10;

// Reverse digits by swapping every two parallel elements
for (int i = 0, j = ndigits-1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
    int tmp = digits[i];
    digits[i] = digits[j];
    digits[j] = tmp;
}

for (int i = 0; i < ndigits; ++i)
    printf("%d\t", digits[i]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I was writing my response when the first answer showed up. This will work just fine. The loop in the middle basically isolates each digit by removing all the ones in front of it and then dividing it down to the ones place before adding it to the array.