# C++ Compile Time Check for Sideffects

Tags: c++, functional-programming, purely-functional

Some compilers support [pure and const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798188/pure-const-function-attributes-in-different-compilers), but do any offer to check that these assertions hold? For example:

```
int global_value = 42;
const int global_value_const = 42;

int MyPureFunction  __attribute__ (( pure_check? )) (
  int input,
  int* input_ptr,
  const int* input_const_ptr,
  int foo& input_ref,
  const int& input_const_ref)
{
   int temporary = input;    // Valid, can read local but mutable state.

   global_value += temporary;        // Invalid, cannot mutate external state
   temporary += global_value;        // Invalid,  cannot read non-const global data.
   temporary += global_value_const;  // Valid, can read const global data.

   temporary += *input_ptr;        // Invalid, cannot derefernece non-const ptr.
   temporary += *input_const_ptr;  // Valid, can dereference a const ptr.
   temporary += input_ref;         // Invalid, cannot use non-const reference.
   temporary += foo->value;        // Valid, can reference a const reference.

   return temporary;     // Valid., if all invalid statements above are removed...
}
```

Comment: A `constexpr` would be _pure_, though its more restricted than a _pure_ function

Comment: If I were the only one using this it would suffice (I could use a series of functions much like the bind operation in a monad), but other people will use this and that would be too complicated for them. I need it to be a good old regular multi-statement function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do any offer to check that these assertions hold

There are no C++ compilers that implement effect inference or effect typing, so only ad hoc checks for purity would be supported, at best.

For background on effect typing, I suggest Ben Lippmeier's PhD thesis, *[Type Inference and Optimisation for an Impure World](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~benl/papers/thesis/lippmeier-impure-world.pdf)*