# Are there C++ compiler options that allow aggressive removal of all function calls and passed in arguments to functions with empty bodies?

Tags: c++, optimization, parameter-passing, compiler-optimization

```
#include <iostream>

int ExpensiveFunction() {
    // Do expensive calculation
    // ...

    std::cout << "You shouldn't see this!" << std::endl;

    return 42;
}

void print(int num)
{

}

int main()
{
    print(ExpensiveFunction());
    return 0;
}
```

I would like that the compiler recognizes that print is an empty function, thus completely remove the print call and argument evaluation of the statement:

```
print(ExpensiveFunction());
```

However no matter what kind of optimization settings I use (with MSVC) it will always perform the calculations of the expensive function.

I recognize that an optimization that removes the call to ExpensiveFunction may be a destructive optimization, but I feel that this should be possible without converting print into a macro that will be compiled out in the most optimized configuration.

Is it at all possible to direct any C++ compiler to do this?

**EDIT:** I've added a std::cout statement

Comment: You can [experiment](https://godbolt.org/z/bA59Ak) with various compilers and settings yourself. You can see that GCC 8.1 and Clang 8.0.0 both elided the call entirely, at least with `-O3`.

Comment: The compiler can only do so if `ExpensiveFunction()` does not have observable side effects. To make that assertion the compiler must probably see the source code of the function, either because it is present in the translation unit or because you enable link time / whole program optimization.

Comment: True (about side-effects), but when I try MSVC on the Godbolt site, even the trivial `ExpensiveFunction` is still called.

Comment: @Useless Make sure to use the proper optimization options. The default is unoptimized; MSVC removes the calls both with /O2 (speed) and /Ox (space). *-O2 does not have any effect.*

Comment: Also, if I declare `ExpensiveFunction()` extern, without providing the implementation, the compiler simply calls `ExpensiveFunction()` directly (because it cannot know it does not have side effects) and omits the empty `print()` wrapper entirely. When we tell gcc via `__attribute__ ((pure))` that there are no side-effects gcc dutifully removes the call even without source.

Comment: Yep, I realized I forgot about Microsoft's novelty switch syntax

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Sorry for omitting any implementation for `ExpensiveFunction`. I've edited the example to clarify. I understand from your comments and comments below that it's impossible to optimize this out, because the function has side effects? I'm left to defining macros to be able to compile out the entire `print(ExpensiveFunction());` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it at all possible to direct any C++ compiler to do this?

Probably not directly - it's a quality-of-implementation issue.

Both Clang and GCC (for the recent versions tested), do this with the standard `-O3` flag. Actually, they even do it with `-O1` and `-O2` ... you have to disable optimization completely for them to emit the call to `ExpensiveFunction`.

A quick attempt with x64 MSVC 19.24 shows it will optimize out the call as well, at least with `/O2`.

MSVC command-line options are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=vs-2019).

GCC command-line options are in the manual, optimization-specific ones are [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options).

In general you can see what several different compilers do to the same code simultaneously with Matt Godbolt's compiler explorer, like [so](https://godbolt.org/z/UsXzoi).

---

Note that this is only testing your sample code - if `ExpensiveFunction` has observable side-effects, the optimizer will be unable to remove it.

---

**Edit** so it turns out that `ExpensiveFunction` *does* have observable side-effects.

> I recognize that an optimization that removes the call to ExpensiveFunction may be a destructive optimization,

There is no such thing as a "destructive optimization". Optimization is something that improves the non-functional characteristics of your program (typically performance or size) *without changing the functional characteristics*, which are specifically defined as the visible side-effects.

Let's consider your title, corrected to match the body of the question:

> Are there C++ compiler options that allow aggressive removal of all function calls and passed in arguments to functions with **non-empty** bodies?

If the compiler is free to speed up your code by throwing away things that take time *even if they have an externally-observable effect*, life becomes very simple: it can just replace every program with

```
int main() {}
```

and call it a "destructive optimization". This is a correct solution to your corrected title, right?

> ... but I feel that this should be possible without converting print into a macro that will be compiled out in the most optimized configuration.

You can alternatively make the body of `ExpensiveFunction` conditional, if for example it is really debug output whose observable side-effect you want to disable in some builds

```
int ExpensiveFunction() {
    #ifndef DEBUG
    // Do expensive calculation
    // ...

    std::cout << "You shouldn't see this!" << std::endl;
    #endif
    return 42;
}
```

But disabling code that has observable side-effects *must* always be under your manual control, unless you're happy with my extra-reductive whole-program optimization above.

Comment: I can confirm that on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/x8ujFa) for gcc. If I declare the functions static, i.e. no external linking, the compiler does not even emit any code or symbol for them.

Comment: ("The compiler" above being gcc. MSVC emits code even for static functions but does also not call them in main.)

Comment: To be fair, it wouldn't be unusual for unused functions to be kept around until link time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've clarified my example. With a std::cout statement it won't be compiled out with any optimization flags, so it's impossible that it will be removed by any compiler because it has side-effects? I'm left to defining macros for each function I want to have removed this way?

Comment: If you have a function with a side-effect, it will always be called, yes. Of course! Otherwise `cout` statements could be removed so long as you don't look at the return value ... If the compiler optimizes out functions with side-effects, it's changing the behaviour of your program, and not just its performance.

Comment: Ok thanks, accepting this as an answer. I'll have to use macros then that call this function, so those will be compiled out in release builds and I understand why now :)

Answer (score 3):

For GCC and Clang, you can use `__attribute__((pure))` to reassure the compiler that `ExpensiveFunction()` doesn't have any side effects and can be elided if its result is not used. In some simple cases these compilers can figure out the pure-ness of a function anyway, but using the attribute allows you to get this effect in more complex cases and for functions defined in other translation units.

Unfortunately, MSVC doesn't have any equivalent facility that I'm aware of. See [pure/const function attributes in different compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798188/pure-const-function-attributes-in-different-compilers) for more.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It's a shame MSVC doesn't have this. MSVC is also reluctant to run some `constexpr` functions at compile time where other compilers have no problem doing this. I always have to define a `constexpr` variable first to force the compiler to do this :(

Answer (score 1):

For MSVC, you'd need `/O2` (optimize), `/GL`+`/LTCG` (link-time code generation) and `/OPT:REF` (eliminate functions and data that are never referenced).