does fetching values into local variables allow greater optimization in C/C++?
I've often wondered this.  Suppose you've got a loop in a function or method, like:
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    ...do stuff including function/method calls...;

Suppose count is some variable external to the function – a global variable, a data member of the object performing the loop, whatever.  Not a local variable.  It seems to me that the compiler doesn't know, in general, whether count might change in value across the work that the loop does, and therefore it has to re-fetch the value of count each time through the loop, from whatever memory location it lives in; it can't, for example, be kept in a register.  If you instead wrote:
int local_count = count;

for (int i = 0; i < local_count; ++i)
    ...do stuff including function/method calls...;

then you're telling the compiler "the value of count should be cached in a local variable and used, even if the original value were to change".  That would allow it to be, for example, placed in a register for the duration of the loop.
Assume that the value of count does not, in fact, change for the duration of the loop.  Does this difference in coding style make a performance difference or not, with a typical modern compiler?  How smart at compilers at figuring out "this value won't change and doesn't need to be re-fetched"?  Note I'm not asking about volatile, which I understand; I'm asking about the possibility that the do stuff section of the code changes the value of count (which I know doesn't happen, but the compiler perhaps does not know).
This comes up even in simpler situations like:
use non-local variable foo;
...do stuff...;
use non-local variable foo again;

Assume that I know the value of foo doesn't change.  Should I still cache its value in a local variable for maximal performance?  Like:
auto local_foo = foo;

use local_foo;
...do stuff...;
use local_foo again;

I imagine this will depend on the compiler, but I'm hoping some general, useful statements can be made about about how smart/dumb modern compilers tend to be about drawing this inference that a value has not changed, when set to a high optimization level.  Does it depend on inlining?  Link-time optimization?  Other considerations, such as the use of pointers in the the "do stuff" sections that the compiler presumably cannot assume do not point at the external variable in question?  Is there any more elegant way of handling this problem than making local-variable copies of stuff all over the place?
(Please don't reply about premature optimization, tell me not to worry about such tiny performance details, etc.; I am asking specifically about the context where every little bit of performance really does matter for the code in question.  I work on simulations that take days or weeks to run, often with an extreme hotspot in a short section of code.  And please don't tell me I ought to hand-code such performance-sensitive code in assembler if I care so much; I'd love to, but my software has to run cross-platform on end-user machines that might be macOS, Linux, or Windows, so assembly is a non-starter, and indeed I don't know what compiler I'll be on.  But I really do need to squeeze maximum performance out of the compiler, to the extent possible.)

The state of optimization in the big three compilers is close to ideal in regard to value lifetime analysis. That is, if you write code that uses some object x (here x means some lvalue expression; it may be an external variable or an array element or a pointed-to object) or you write semantically equivalent code that defines a local const T t = x; and then uses t, then the compilers will largely generate equivalent code.
A corollary to that is that, since we expect the generated code to be equivalent, we should prefer the code that is easier for humans to read and work with.
However, the question is not strictly about semantically equivalent code. If a routine has const T t = x; and then calls some routine not visible in the current translation unit, the compiler might not be able to determine that x does not change during the call, whereas it can see that t does not change. Or there can even be code in the routine that is not equivalent.  For example, if a routine has two parameters int *a and int *b, and x is a[3], then b[2] = 7; b[3] = a[3]; and b[2] = 7; b[3] = t; are not equivalent because b[2] = 7; might change x (a[3]), but it cannot change t.
Now, suppose you know that x does not change during execution of the routine, at least not as long as the routine is called the way it is supposed to be called. Then, by defining const T t = x; and thereafter using t in place of x, you are giving the compiler extra information. You are telling the compiler, “This value will not change during execution of this routine.” The compiler can see that t does not change whereas it might not have been able to see that x does not change. Adding information to an optimizer should only enable it to make better decisions. It can enable optimizations that might not otherwise be allowed.
Of course, optimizers are not always perfect. We still use some heuristics to try to figure out the best code. But, in general, modern optimizers are very good, and the more information you give them, the better a result you will get. So it is generally preferable to define local variables to “cache” values you use repeatedly.
It is possible this can go too far. If a routine works with a lot of values, then const T t = x; can become an additional value that must be spilled to the stack at some point. Or it could cause some value other than t be spilled to the stack.
So there is no absolute rule that using local variables like this will improve performance (or at least not impair it), but it is generally a good idea.

Here is an example showing that.

@JérômeRichard that's very neat; I've never seen that website before.  Thanks!

A local non-escaping variable doesn't really need to be const; all major compilers will spot that there's no modification. Still, it's a good idea for readability. It tells humans up front that there is no modification.

Hi Eric!  Have a look at Craig Estey's answer below, and his benchmark results.  I'm very curious what you think about them.  They seem to me to suggest that your "generally a good idea" conclusion might be overly optimistic, because it looks like the local cache actually slows things down even in a very simple case, perhaps because of needing to save/restore the local cache to the stack across the function call – something nobody has discussed here yet, and hadn't occurred to me.  Thoughts?

Referring to the code below ...

If a function has a simple loop, it can fetch count just once (under optimization) and keep the value in a register variable. (e.g. simple in the example below)

If, however, the function calls another function it must refetch count on each iteration. It must do this because the called function may change the value of count (e.g. call_modify)

So, keeping a local copy of count can provide optimization speedup (e.g. call_cached). This example explicitly tells the compiler that we do not care if the called function modifies count: we want the original value.

Another way we can force optimization is to declare the called function as pure or const. That is, [loosely] it has no side effects. (e.g.) __attribute__((pure)) (or whatever the [[pure]] standard form is). (e.g. call_safe below). See below for the exact definition(s).



Clipped from info gcc:

'pure'
Many functions have no effects except the return value and their
return value depends only on the parameters and/or global
variables.  Calls to such functions can be subject to common
subexpression elimination and loop optimization just as an
arithmetic operator would be.


'const'
Many functions do not examine any values except their arguments,
and have no effects except to return a value.  Calls to such
functions lend themselves to optimization such as common
subexpression elimination.


Consider the following:
int count;
int array[100];
int *ptr;
int callee_modify(int);
int callee_safe(int) __attribute__((const));

void
simple(void)
{

    // simple loop: count will be fetched once and cached in a register variable
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        array[idx] = ptr[idx];
}

void
call_modify(void)
{

    // compiler can't know whether count is modified by callee, so it must be
    // refetched on each iteration
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        array[idx] = callee_modify(idx);
}

void
call_cached(void)
{
    int lcount = count;

    // we can tell the compiler we wish to cache count in a register by using
    // the local variable
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < lcount;  ++idx)
        array[idx] = callee_modify(idx);
}

void
call_safe(void)
{

    // because the function is marked pure and/or const, we get the same
    // optimization as simple
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        array[idx] = callee_safe(idx);
}

int
main(void)
{

    simple();
    call_modify();
    call_cached();
    call_safe();

    return 0;
}


The cleaned up assembler (with -O2) is:
simple:
.LFB0:
    movl    count(%rip), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jle .L1
    leal    -1(%rax), %ecx
    movq    ptr(%rip), %rsi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp .L3
.L4:
    movq    %rdx, %rax
.L3:
    movl    (%rsi,%rax,4), %edx
    movl    %edx, array(,%rax,4)
    leaq    1(%rax), %rdx
    cmpq    %rcx, %rax
    jne .L4
.L1:
    ret
.LFE0:

call_modify:
.LFB1:
    movl    count(%rip), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jle .L11
    pushq   %rbx
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
.L8:
    movl    %ebx, %edi
    call    callee_modify
    movl    %eax, array(,%rbx,4)
    addq    $1, %rbx
    cmpl    %ebx, count(%rip)
    jg  .L8
    popq    %rbx
    ret
.L11:
    ret
.LFE1:

call_cached:
.LFB2:
    movl    count(%rip), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jle .L19
    pushq   %rbp
    leal    -1(%rax), %ebp
    pushq   %rbx
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    subq    $8, %rsp
    jmp .L16
.L17:
    movq    %rax, %rbx
.L16:
    movl    %ebx, %edi
    call    callee_modify
    movl    %eax, array(,%rbx,4)
    leaq    1(%rbx), %rax
    cmpq    %rbp, %rbx
    jne .L17
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    ret
.L19:
    ret
.LFE2:

call_safe:
.LFB3:
    movl    count(%rip), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jle .L27
    pushq   %rbp
    leal    -1(%rax), %ebp
    pushq   %rbx
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    subq    $8, %rsp
    jmp .L24
.L25:
    movq    %rax, %rbx
.L24:
    movl    %ebx, %edi
    call    callee_safe
    movl    %eax, array(,%rbx,4)
    leaq    1(%rbx), %rax
    cmpq    %rbp, %rbx
    jne .L25
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    ret
.L27:
    ret
.LFE3:

main:
.LFB4:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    call    simple
    call    call_modify
    call    call_cached
    call    call_safe
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
.LFE4:


For reference, here is a possible definition of callee:
extern int count;
extern int array[];

int
callee_modify(int idx)
{

    if (array[idx] == -1)
        count = idx + 1;

    return idx + 1;
}

int
callee_safe(int idx)
{

    return idx + 1;
}

int
callee_nomod(int idx)
{

    return idx + 1;
}


The above examples are a bit contrived, but illustrate why the count optimization can't be performed if the loop calls a function that does not have special attributes.

UPDATE:
I've modified the test example to produce a benchmark program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifndef COUNT
#define COUNT       10000000
#endif

int count;
int *ptr = NULL;
int array[COUNT];
int array2[COUNT];

int callee_modify(int);
int callee_safe(int) __attribute__((pure));
int callee_nomod(int);

void
simple(void)
{

    // simple loop: count will be fetched once and cached in a register variable
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        array[idx] = ptr[idx];
}

void
call_modify(void) {

    // compiler can't know whether count is modified by callee, so it must be
    // refetched on each iteration
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        array[idx] = callee_modify(idx);
}

void
call_cached(void)
{
    int lcount = count;

    // we can tell the compiler we wish to cache count in a register by using
    // the local variable
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < lcount;  ++idx)
        array[idx] = callee_modify(idx);
}

void
call_safe(void)
{

    // because the function is marked "pure" and/or const, we get the same
    // optimization as simple
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        array[idx] = callee_safe(idx);
}

void
call_nomod(void)
{

    // because the function is marked "pure" and/or const, we get the same
    // optimization as simple
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        array[idx] = callee_nomod(idx);
}

void
call_cached_nomod(void)
{
    int lcount = count;

    // because the function is marked "pure" and/or const, we get the same
    // optimization as simple
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < lcount;  ++idx)
        array[idx] = callee_nomod(idx);
}

typedef long long tsc_t;

tsc_t
tscget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    tsc_t tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);

    tsc = ts.tv_sec;
    tsc *= 1000000000;
    tsc += ts.tv_nsec;

    return tsc;
}

double
tscsec(tsc_t tsc)
{
    double sec;

    sec = tsc;
    sec /= 1e9;

    return sec;
}

struct test {
    void (*fnc)(void);
    const char *sym;
    tsc_t elap;
};

void
dotest(struct test *test)
{
    test->elap = 1LL << 62;

    // take fastest time to account for caching/timeslicing
    for (int iter = 1;  iter <= 5;  ++iter) {
        tsc_t tscbeg = tscget();

        test->fnc();

        tsc_t tscend = tscget();
        tscend -= tscbeg;

        if (tscend < test->elap)
            test->elap = tscend;
    }

#if 0
    printf("%.9f %s\n",tscsec(tscbest),sym);
#endif
}

#define countof(_arr)       sizeof(_arr) / sizeof(_arr[0])

int
cmp(const void *lhsp,const void *rhsp)
{
    const struct test *lhs = lhsp;
    const struct test *rhs = rhsp;
    int ret;

    do {
        ret = -1;
        if (lhs->elap < rhs->elap)
            break;

        ret = 1;
        if (lhs->elap > rhs->elap)
            break;

        ret = 0;
    } while (0);

    return ret;
}

#define TEST(_fnc) \
    { \
        .fnc = _fnc, .sym = #_fnc \
    }

struct test tests[] = {
    TEST(simple),
    TEST(call_modify),
    TEST(call_cached),
    TEST(call_safe),
    TEST(call_nomod),
    TEST(call_cached_nomod),
};
#define ALLTEST \
    struct test *test = tests;  test < &tests[countof(tests)];  ++test

int
main(void)
{

    ptr = &array2[0];
    count = COUNT;

    printf("COUNT: %d\n",COUNT);

    for (ALLTEST)
        dotest(test);

    qsort(tests,countof(tests),sizeof(struct test),cmp);

    tsc_t first = tests[0].elap;
    for (ALLTEST) {
        printf("%.9f %.9f %s\n",
            tscsec(test->elap),tscsec(test->elap - first),test->sym);
        first = test->elap;
    }

    return 0;
}

Here is the output for various count values:
COUNT: 1000
0.000001057 0.000000000 simple
0.000002085 0.000001028 call_safe
0.000002088 0.000000003 call_modify
0.000002427 0.000000339 call_cached
0.000002771 0.000000344 call_nomod
0.000003113 0.000000342 call_cached_nomod

COUNT: 10000
0.000010800 0.000000000 simple
0.000020586 0.000009786 call_safe
0.000020589 0.000000003 call_modify
0.000024012 0.000003423 call_cached
0.000028750 0.000004738 call_nomod
0.000032330 0.000003580 call_cached_nomod

COUNT: 100000
0.000102831 0.000000000 simple
0.000205608 0.000102777 call_safe
0.000205609 0.000000001 call_modify
0.000239947 0.000034338 call_cached
0.000274132 0.000034185 call_nomod
0.000308391 0.000034259 call_cached_nomod

COUNT: 1000000
0.001076245 0.000000000 simple
0.002094210 0.001017965 call_modify
0.002217435 0.000123225 call_safe
0.002463532 0.000246097 call_cached
0.002786411 0.000322879 call_nomod
0.003131034 0.000344623 call_cached_nomod

COUNT: 10000000
0.010405105 0.000000000 simple
0.020755958 0.010350853 call_safe
0.021346993 0.000591035 call_modify
0.024852389 0.003505396 call_cached
0.027612375 0.002759986 call_nomod
0.031151922 0.003539547 call_cached_nomod

COUNT: 100000000
0.104571271 0.000000000 simple
0.208059662 0.103488391 call_safe
0.214165594 0.006105932 call_modify
0.247594066 0.033428472 call_cached
0.279600649 0.032006583 call_nomod
0.311631119 0.032030470 call_cached_nomod


Very interesting; I hadn't encountered const/pure applied to functions before.  Here is a SO post about them, which was helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798188/pure-const-function-attributes-in-different-compilers

@bhaller Personally, I don't use them (unless a standard header has) them. I usually just do the local variable for speed critical sections. When I started C coding (1981), there were no optimizing compilers. So, we had to use local/automatic vars and use register explicitly. I've found that benchmarking is critical. In certain cases, doing local is faster and slower in others.

@bhaller The attributes can be hazardous for anything but low level primitives (e.g strlen). That's because if funcA is marked pure and it calls funcB, then funcB must also be pure-like (even if it's not marked). Thereafter, if funcB (not knowing that funcA needs it to be pure) changes, things can break (in subtle ways). It's hard to do this for many funcs in a large code base that has (e.g.) 10 levels of function calls.

Interesting benchmarks!  They show that caching count is actually detrimental to performance, right?  call_cached is always slower than call_modify, and call_cached_nomod is always slower than call_nomod.  At a guess, perhaps this is because the ABI requires the local variable to get pushed out to stack for the function call, to save its value, and then restored from stack after the function call, whereas without the caching count is re-fetched each time, which is actually fewer memory accesses?  So does this benchmark indicate that caching is a bad idea even in this simple case?

This might well be platform-dependent, ABI-dependent, etc. – but maybe it's actually pretty general?  What's your read on it?  I'm hoping for some take-home lessons from this, about how I ought to think about this question of local caching and when it is likely to be a good/bad idea.  So far, your benchmark results have shifted me pretty strongly to thinking it is a bad idea, since this is a very simple case where I would have expected it to be a clear win!

Perhaps it would be interesting to look at how the benchmark results change with (1) inlining of the called function, and (2) link-time optimization.  Both of those things would presumably allow the compiler to fix the problem, if the problem is indeed the need to save/restore the local variable to the stack across the function call, right?

@CraigEstey, you might not have had access to optimizing compilers, but they did exist (even if they weren't as capable as modern ones).  Even the original FORTRAN I compiler (1957) could do things like moving invariant code out of loops or allocate registers in a reasonably optimal way.

I'll give you the answer you want, and the answer you do not want.
A compiler is permitted to optimize away any operation that it can predict the results of.  For these purposes, other threads can be ignored, as the spec is written such that the optimizer does not need to consider the effect of other threads unless a synchronization point occurs.  This is true for local and global variables.  Indeed, the compiler is free to store a copy of a global variable in a register if it feels this is appropriate.
So in this sense, a local variable and a global variable are going to have equivalent behaviors unless it can predict the value of a local variable and not a global.  Of course, this is the corner case you ask about.  You mention the possibility of the count being stored in a register, which is a decidedly compiler/platform specific concept.
Now the bad news.  You say you don't want calls of premature optimization, but this is exactly what this is, so you will need to deal with that.  For most for loops, the major compilers are very good at analyzing these sorts of operations.  In most cases, the compilers will output comparable-if-not-identical results.
The hard case is when the compiler cannot know the correct answer.  This happens if one calls a function that is not in the current translation unit.  In such cases, it is hard to prove that the global variable did not change, so the compiler has to retrieve it every time.  In this sense a local variable may be faster.  I say may because you actually do need to profile this one each individual platform/compiler you are interested in.  A local variable is not free.  In particular, it can take up a different cache lane on the processor and potentially even slow things down.  Whether it does or does not depends heavily on the exact compiler.  Also worth considering is that that register variable you are thinking you might get may be put in a temporary register which needs to be saved off.  The cost of saving it off will almost certainly be more expensive, so you actually lose gains.
The real problem is:

I am asking specifically about the context where every little bit of performance really does matter for the code in question.

As someone who also makes simulations that can run for a long time, this statement is almost never true.  Unless you are working in a hard realtime environment and already running up against performance limits, a difference in runtime of 0.00001% simply is not worth considering, especially when it is possible to slow things down even worse due to things like cache coherency.
If you are truly in such a situation, I would not focus on the cost of the fetch of a global that may or may not occur.  My focus would be on the function prolog and epilog that has to be appended to the function call inside the for loop that is causing the compiler to not optimize better.  These are an order of magnitude more expensive than a mere fetch (assuming a cache hit.  In the case of a cache miss, no saving of local variables will save you).  If you really are in that one-in-a-million case where that little bit of performance matters, you're also in the situation where you're willing to profile the compilers and willing to take the effort to make the function being called appear in the translation unit so that the optimizers can take a swing at it.
In my opinion (and this part really is just an opinion), the only corner case I have found where this sort of game becomes worthwhile is when you're calling an extremely small function (like return x + 1;) because that's what the architecture said needed to be done.  In these cases, solving the problem at the architecture level is often far more effective than trying to solve it at the compiler level.  It may be effective to create a special case for these extremely short functions which can be captured within the translation unit, and a more general case for longer functions which exhibit these issues.

"a difference in runtime of 0.00001% simply is not worth considering" – certainly, of course.  But the timing examples in another answer to this question are showing that this consideration can have a MUCH larger impact than that – 10-20%.  That is very much worth thinking about.  Of course the impact might be smaller in a real-world situation, but if it affects a hotspot in my code by even 1%, that really matters.  Those are precisely the kinds of considerations I'm trying to understand better.

"My focus would be on the function prolog and epilog that has to be appended to the function call inside the for loop that is causing the compiler to not optimize better."  I'm very curious to hear more about your thinking on this.  Perhaps this comment thread is not the place, however.  :->  Can you recommend a link?  Or even a whole book on optimization techniques, not written for the compiler designer/writer, but for the user of a modern compiler?  I would read such a book with great fascination!  Thanks!

@bhaller I don't know about a book.  These things are typically thought of on a compiler/platform basis.  I started with Microsoft's page on the x64 ABI which covers the prologue and epilog mandated by x64.  You can also find other documents covering things like calling conventions which can matter.  I think Intel actually owns the official definitions, but I liked the wording of MS's pages on these topics.

In the end, the answer is heavily profile oriented.  As another example of one of those low level things, x86 function calls can be quite different between older architectures which use the 8087 FPU and newer ones that can use SSE.  The register alllocations for those architectures are very different, so some optimizations for one are actually de-optimizations for the other.

Another topic that could be worth researching are cache-oblivious algorithms.  Caches can be really frustrating because you can write the same assembly on two computers with different processors and get different performance due to the caching algorithms.  Worse, those algorithms are proprietary, so they won't tell you how they work.  Cache oblivious algorithms are designed carefully to be relatively agnostic to such differences.


Suppose count is some variable external to the function

Yes, absolutely, copy it into a local const variable, provided it is immune to change. That not only provides a good optimisation hint, it ensures you cannot be accidentally modifying count in the logic below, especially from a typo.
Most compilers nowadays will warn if you did something like:
if (count = 17) ... // special handling for item 17

How smart at compilers at figuring out "this value won't change and doesn't need to be re-fetched"?

There's a limit on how smart they can be at evaluating functions that you call, especially if they are in a different compilation unit. In most cases, I'm pretty sure they will just assume count is untrusted and may have changed.
Threads
What nobody else seems to have pointed out - if a value is other than local to this function, there are no guarantees it cannot be updated by another thread. Hence count cannot be trusted between iterations.
As discussed in the comments below, there's a misunderstanding that volatile must be used to mark things that can be changed by threads and that's completely wrong. The special case of volatile is for things like memory-mapped ports, where an external influence can change a value regardless of C++ operations.
I found a great discussion of this and thread implications in GoTW 95

a C++ volatile variable should be viewed as portal into a different universe beyond the language — a memory location that by definition does not obey the language’s memory model because that memory location is accessed by hardware (e.g., written to by a daughter card), have more than one address, or is otherwise “strange” and beyond the language. So C++ volatile variables are universally an exception to every guideline about synchronization because are always inherently “racy” and unsynchronizable using the normal tools (mutexes, atomics, etc.) and more generally exist outside all normal of the language and compiler including that they generally cannot be optimized by the compiler (because the compiler isn’t allowed to know their semantics;


"there are no guarantees it cannot be updated by another thread." Without synchronization, it would be UB to modify that variable from another thread...

@AndyDent as I wrote, this question is not about volatile and multithreading.  Unless count is marked as volatile, my understanding is that it is not allowed to be modified by another thread.  If it got modified by another thread anyway, then as @Jarod42 points out, it would be UB, because the compiler is allowed to assume that it cannot occur.

@Jarod42: Technically, it could be modified by another thread, with a synchronized access on the current thread hidden in a callee in another translation unit. But that's just a more complicated way of saying that a callee in a different translation unit can alter count. Practically, the compiler has to reload count afterwards.

With regard to threading, compilers are allowed to offer stronger guarantees than mandated by the Standard, and a lot of existing code relies upon compilers treating an ordinary read of a word-size-or-smaller primitive as yielding some bit pattern that the primitive has held or will hold sometime within its lifetime--semantics similar to Java and .NET.  If all such values would satisfy application requirements, requiring that programmers use volatile would block more optimizations than would be blocked by the above guarantee.  The failure of the Standard to impose a mandate...

...was never meant to imply that general-purpose implementations shouldn't behave as specified anyhow whenever doing so could be useful and practical.

My understanding of volatile is that it exists for things like memory-mapped systems, where values that have no clear indication of change may be changed. Double checked lookin at p808 of Special Edition of The C++ Programming Language and also see http://web.archive.org/web/20160208184448/https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming

The answer is actually a lot more straightforward and terse than it seems;
In the for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) loop, the second part of the for loop (i < count), tells the compiler that after i is of the same value as count, the for loop has reached its end. The value of count here will not change, because if it does, then the compiler cannot have a way to know when to end the for loop. count can change during the for loop, and the end of the for loop with change with it.
Big thank you to all of the comments under this post for pointing out my blunders
EDIT: Forgot to answer the performance part of the OP's question.
EDIT2: Fixed the lack of knowledge on my part.
As for performance, the "general rule" is to declare all variables that will not change as const, or, alternatively,constexpr (or both). Declaring count as const will tell the compiler that there is no chance that count will change (don't use const if it's the size of a dynamic array), which does have an increase in performance. But for the for loop, it doesn't matter.

That's not really how optimization works. If there's some code in the loop body where some function parameter int* x is modified, and count has external linkage, then count would have to be re-loaded from memory at each lap in the loop because the compiler can't assume that count didn't get modified when we wrote something to *x. If not for that, the compiler could have stored count in a fast register. So count might very well change during the execution of the loop even in a single-threaded program.

You can only use const if count never changes after its initialization. If it's the length of a dynamic array, that's not true. I think the premise is that it can change, but doesn't change during this loop.

@Lundin I always thought that that is undefined behavior to modify the condition of the for loop. Also, if count was const, it would most certainly result in a segmentation fault. Can you please explain it further, or give a link? I would like to learn more.

This is just wrong logic. For example: int count = 5; for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) { count += (i%2); std::cout << count << '\n'; } clearly modifies count in the loop, in 50% of the iterations. Yet this still runs, and completes. The compiler just needs to check i<count every time. The compiler doesn't need to know up front how often that is.

It's not UB, you can access a volatile from there or call a function etc. What I describe is "pointer aliasing" meaning that a variable and pointers to variables may all refer to the same object and the compiler can generate more efficient code depending on if it can assume that they aren't the same. That's why the restrict keyword was invented, to give the compiler a guarantee that it isn't dealing with the same object. ->

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/ojK4E9EPG. In the former version, the iterator is compared against a value on the stack. cmp DWORD PTR count[rip], eax. Meaning count is reloaded from RAM at each lap of the loop, it can't be stored in a register. In the second version we told the compiler that x and count are definitely different variables. After which the compiler checks if count is zero - if so don't touch x. But once that is concluded, it just skips the whole loop and just copies count into x. Which is obviously way more efficient than the former version.
